# smooth transition between pages when redirecting with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, transition

I am trying to get a smooth transition when I redirect users. First by fading out the page then redirecting and and fadeIn.

Here is my redirect

```
if ( data.redirect != undefined )
{
        $("#toppanel").slideUp(1000);       
        $("#content").fadeOut(2000, function() {
        window.location = data.redirect;
    });
```

My next page has a javascript in the header like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $("div.container_16").first().hide();
    $(".grid_16").first().hide();

    $("div.container_16").first().fadeIn(2000);
    $(".grid_16").first().slideDown(4000);
```

This almost work except for a few milli sec where the second page loads then turns blank and fades in. How do I fix this? Do I need to change the css or html?

Comment: Updated my post, hopefully, with a reusable solution. Tell me how it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix to this would be:

**CSS**

```
body{
    display:none;
}
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('body').show();
    $("div.container_16").first().hide();
    $(".grid_16").first().hide();
    $("div.container_16").first().fadeIn(2000);
    $(".grid_16").first().slideDown(4000);
}
```

You should know that 1 second is a lot of time for a web user. And basically taking 6s extra to just move to another page could be very costly to your user base. I hope you offer a solution without these kind of effects.

**UPDATE**

**CSS**

```
/*
 * overflow => so you don't get a scrollbar
 * visiblity => so all content is hidden
 * background => so you get a black background
 */

.bodyExtra{
    overflow:hidden;
    visibility:none;
    background:#000;
}
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div.container_16").first().hide();
        $(".grid_16").first().hide();
        $('body').removeClass('bodyExtra');
        $("div.container_16").first().fadeIn(2000);
        $(".grid_16").first().slideDown(4000);
    });
}
```

The logic behind this is to make your page work as a buffer zone. You then hide the elements you want to fade in, remove the class from body and fade everything in.

**UPDATE 2013.09.01**

I see this answer is still generating some traffic and I have to admit, since the initial answer in 2011, I have an addition to make

**HTML/CSS**

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bodyExtra{
            overflow:auto !important;
            visibility:visibile !important;
        }
    </style>
</noscript>
```

This can also be done with a `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="no-js.css" />` tag.
The idea behind this is to fix the disabled javascript issue described by theazureshadow in the comments.

Comment: It's a bad idea to hide anything with css that you intend to show with javascript.

Comment: I'm reworking my answer, `display:none` is still giving the flicker since he wanted a black background. Reason for bad please.

Comment: If they don't have javascript enabled, they'll hide the content with css, but then be unable to show it with javascript. Blank page; confused users. I prefer my solution of hiding only the elements that he wants hidden, and leaving the rest to load normally.

Comment: @theazureshadow somewhat fixed the issue described, seeing as how people are still visiting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting what is called a "flash of unstyled content" or FUC. You could wrap your second page in a container and hide that via css (`display: none;`) and then fade in when it's loaded.

Comment: Actually it's called a [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). Just saying...

Comment: Bad idea to hide it with css.

Comment: @theaszureshadow it's not a bad idea to hide it with css. it's 2011, virtually everyone has javascript turned on. even most mobile browsers support JS now. there's really no other way to avoid FOUC (thanks khez). your solution of adding a class with javascript will not prevent FOUC either, since you still have to wait for the JS to download and then execute, unless you're loading your JS in the head of your document, which means you're holding everything up.

Answer (score 0):

*Don't* use pure css to hide the content originally. If you do, users with JavaScript turned off will not see your content. Instead, only hide when javascript is available.

```
.js-enabled div.container_16,
.js-enabled .grid_16 {
  display: none;
}
```

Include this line of javascript at the very top of the body:

```
$(document.body).addClass('js-enabled');
```

Then in your animation function, after you've hidden `.grid_16`, include this line to return things to normal:

```
$(document.body).removeClass('js-enabled');
```

If you want, you can be more specific and target the hiding styles to the particular elements you want to hide. But I don't know if that's practical for your case -- too few details.