# smooth transition between html pages

Tags: jquery, transition, smoothing

When I click on a link, for example in index.html and I click "contact" which is external "contact.html" I want to create a smooth transition. 
Give me some hints...

Example:

```
<a id="map"  href="otherPage.html" target="_self">
     <img src="images/icons/map.png" width="100" height="100">
</a>
```

I don't want otherPage.html to load immediately, I want it to appear very smoothly/slowly

Comment: you may need to add a bit more detail about what you are trying to achieve. Do you mean you want to e.g. slide (animate) the new page in? Similar to this question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630166/smooth-transition-between-pages-when-redirecting-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may want to use a ajax-navigation system.
When you click on a link, you send an ajax request for the desired page and show it's contents into the current page (without refreshing it).

here's an example of a site i've built using the same "smooth navigation" technique : http://www.opisband.ro/

Comment: link isn't working any more. Can you share a valid one pls ? thx in advance

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
var speed = 'slow';

$('html, body').hide();

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html, body').fadeIn(speed, function() {
        $('a[href], button[href]').click(function(event) {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (url.indexOf('#') == 0 || url.indexOf('javascript:') == 0) return;
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').fadeOut(speed, function() {
                window.location = url;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this website: http://www.marcocali.com/ 
and the associated JS: http://www.marcocali.com/public/js/index.js?v=4

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery for that:
http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/

Place the css and js files in the css and js foler of your website, and add to each page you want smooth transition feature:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="default" href="css/main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
```