# Transition to next page

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to redirect to another page after 32 seconds. I need a smooth transition to the second page. Right now the transition is very abrupt and doesnt look very good. Any ideas?

This is my query:

```
function redirect() {
                window.location = $('a').attr('href');

            }

            setTimeout(redirect, 32000);
```

HTML5:

```
<a href="Holiday_Final.htm"></a>
```

Comment: There is no transition. You're doing a redirect. Try looking into an ajax + html5 history api solution, such as [pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com/)

Comment: Is there a better way to transition to the next page without using a redirect? With HTML5 or Jquery? I am not familiar with ajax

Comment: Yes, as per my previous comment.

Comment: Pretty much your only options are: A) Take the suggestion of @ChristianVarga and do some research/learning or B) Have it work the way it does.

Comment: no, basically the browser won't let you do anything to the drawing of the next page. The best you can do is fade out your own page and let the browser do what it does

Comment: Thanks. I will check into pjax

Comment: @jakee Libraries such as pjax allow you to transition between pages using ajax + the HTML5 history api, with a fallback to standard redirects on browsers that don't support it. It's great stuff.

Comment: check out this post if it helps... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630166/smooth-transition-between-pages-when-redirecting-with-jquery

Comment: pics or didn't happen, I wan't to see a working example of this, because it sounds like something that sound completely and utterly impossible. It is not sane that the browser would let you interfere with the user experience of an another site

Comment: and my pov is transitioning to completely other sites, not inside the same host

Comment: I think this may be what I am looking for but I do not need the user to click on a link. I need the page to redirect after 32 seconds:  $("a.transition").click(function(event){        event.preventDefault();        linkLocation = this.href;        $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);          });             function redirectPage() {        window.location = linkLocation;    }});

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect with a fading effect.
You have to use ajax to perform such animation.

But you can try this

```
function redirect() {
    $('body').fadeOut(1000,function(){
        window.location = $('a').attr('href');
    });
}
setTimeout(redirect, 31000);
```

you will have a 1s fadeOut before redirecting (and having no fadeIn, just the abrupt loading of the next page)

Comment: I changed it up a bit. Intsead of redirecting to another page, I added a div to dispaly the image. Everything seems to be working as planned EXCPET the image is displaying before it is intended under the  blue border before disappearing and then dispalying properly within the blue border. The div is called Final. I need another set of eyes to see what I am doing wrong. See: http://jsfiddle.net/lgrand34/AUCUh/7/